# Add ascending serial number field to all existing mongodb documents in a collection

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I have a mongodb collection which looks something like this;

```
[
  {
    "Code": "018906",
    "X": "0.12",
  },
  {
    "Code": "018907",
    "X": "0.18",
  },
  {
    "Code": "018910",
    "X": "0.24",
  },
  {
    "Code": "018916",
    "X": "0.75",
  },
]
```

I want to add an ascending serial number field to all existing mongodb documents inside the collection. After adding, the new collection will look like this;

```
[
  {
    "Serial": 1,
    "Code": "018906",
    "X": "0.12",
  },
  {
    "Serial": 2,
    "Code": "018907",
    "X": "0.18",
  },
  {
    "Serial": 3,
    "Code": "018910",
    "X": "0.24",
  },
  {
    "Serial": 4,
    "Code": "018916",
    "X": "0.75",
  },
]
```

I am open to using any python mongodb library such as pymongo or mongoengine.

I am using python 3.7, mongodb v4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to find all the `_id` in the collection, and use bulk write operation.

```py
from pymongo import UpdateOne


records = db.collection.find({}, {'_id':1})
i = 1
request = []

for record in records:
    request.append(UpdateOne({'_id': record['_id']}, {'$set': {'serial': i}}))
    i=i+1

db.collection.bulk_write(request)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a single aggregation query by grouping up all documents in a single array, then unwinding it with element index included:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      doc: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$doc",
      includeArrayIndex: "doc.Serial"
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$doc"
    }
  },
  {
    $out: "new_collection_name"
  }
])
```

All job is done serverside, no need to load whole collection to the application's memory. If the collection is large enough, you may need to call aggregation with "allowDiskUse".

Prepend it with sorting stage to ensure expected order if required.

Comment: Yes reading docs is not necessary with `$out` & I agree this adds a new field with an ascending serial number which is what needed, but all OP needs to know is it starts at 0..